# Winsorizing or taking the logarithm first?

Tags: data-transformation, outliers, logarithm, winsorizing

I testing if I can describe the StockPRice with EPS (=earnings per share), BookValuePS an ESGscore.

Before I start I winsorized all my variables. Now I want to take the loagrithm of e.g. BookValuePS and I don't know if I should take the logarithm first or winsorize first.

What do you say? :)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you want to take logarithms or winsorize?

Comment: Why not try it both ways?  You should discover it makes no difference, because the log transformation is monotonic.

Comment: It depends on how the Winsorizing is done. OP: how are you choosing the limits on your winsorizing in each case?